# Unable to get Email Id Of logged person in Facebook ios SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a Facebook IOS app to fetch user data(Public Profile,Email) from the Facebook.After implementing login process i am able to fetch first name,last name and url for profile picture of the User but the email i am getting is null. i have passed the permission for getting public Profile and Emial.but i am not getting Email Of the person.

I am using facebook SDK for ios V4.0.1

Here is my code

```
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                     parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, picture, email"}]
                              startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {                    
NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"first_name"]];

NSString *lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"last_name"]];
NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"email"]];
NSString *picurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"picture"]];

 NSLog(@"email is %@", [result objectForKey:@"email"]);

 NSLog(@"picture is %@", [result objectForKey:@"picture"]);
 }
 else{
 NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
 }];
```

I am getting the Following Output:

```
email is (null)
picture is {
    data =     {
        "is_silhouette" = 0;
        url = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50 **************_************_n.jpg?oh=ed5fd60c770cb5f34424b3fcfb4ca174&oe=559F472D&__gda__=1437970763_989a264cf7ec16f5d51b0a58b7e7f609";
    };
}
```

why i am not getting Email Address of the User

Comment: if email ID is available (public) it surely comes else u get only null

Comment: How can i check if email id is Public

Comment: its a default one on Facebook ,we can't do any changes,

Comment: i have made it public but it is still not coming

Comment: try this key also `public_profile`, and see this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/)

Comment: @JuniorBillgates getting email at my end with your code. Have u asked user permission for email while logging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While logging. You must ask user permission for email or else you would get email as (null).

**Would not fetch Email ID**

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginView = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
 loginView.readPermissions =  @[@"public_profile"];
```

IF you login with above permission then you would not be able to get email id it will always be return (null).

**Would fetch Email ID with Public profile**

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginView = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginView.readPermissions =  @[@"email"];
```

Our app gets public_profile permission automatically upon any successful login but it does not get email.

Same goes for custom login as well.

Refer to :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#login-apicalls

Comment: yeah buddy i have asked for 
self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email",@user_profiles];

Comment: @JuniorBillgates how it worked could you tell? what did you change?

Comment: Earlier i was sending 
self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",@"email",@user_profiles];

i changed above with 
self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"email"];

it worked. when i did this webPage said xxxApp will access ur public profile and email id. earlier it was saying that it will fetch only user profile

thanks Mr Dheeraj

Comment: Even if `self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"email"];` is set, there might be a possibility that email is returned nil.
This possibility arises because FB allows users to sign up using contact number/UsedID as well. In such cases, email is not found.

Comment: @cheeseRoot yes it happens if email is not present.

Comment: Yeah. Learnt it the hard way, after app went live.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to assume the logic that setting FBSDKLoginButton.readPermissions to `["public_profile","email"]` would be the way to express that you want the Facebook user's `"public_profile"` and their `"email"` address you will be sorely mistaken. Very confusing in my opinion, the following gives you both the Facebook user's public profile and their email address:

```
FBSDKLoginButton.readPermissions = ["email"]
```